# glGenVertexArrays() does not exist in the GL30 library. (JAVA LWJGL)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/) OpenGL tutorial to render a simple triangle. At the start of the tutorial, under the "The VAO" section, I am told to write the following code:

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
```

My Java code for this C snippet is

```
int VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
```

In [the documentation](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL30.html), it is stated that the GL30 class, which I have imported, includes the method glGenVertexArray() and glBindVertexArray(). Yet IntelliJ fails to see this as a valid method.

My imports:

```
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import java.nio.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;
```

My GLFW Window Hints:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // OpenGL 3
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // For macOS
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

I am using Maven for my dependencies and in my pom.xml I am using the preset "Everything" from the  [LWJGL customizer](https://www.lwjgl.org/customize).

Comment: Thats it - thanks a lot. Is there a way to mark it as an answer? Or maybe you could add it as an answer and I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your IDE does not "see" the `glGenVertexArrays` method is because you did not `import static` the `GL30` static methods, like you did with the `GL11` class.

In order to have the static methods of the class `GL30` resolvable in the scope of your class, you also need to `import static` the methods of `GL30` with:

`import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;`

Additionally, starting with version [3.2.0 of LWJGL 3](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/releases/tag/3.2.0), the versioned classes, like GL11, GL12, GL13, GL20, etc. *inherit* from the respective previous version.

So, when you use at least LWJGL 3.2.0, you can then remove the `import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;` line and *only* have `import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;`.

And, since you request OpenGL version 3.3 from GLFW, and also use the *core* profile, you could just as well use `import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL33C.*;` to have only the OpenGL core functions visible (and not those from the compatibility profile - which you did not request and hence, which won't be available at runtime). This way, you do not accidentally use deprecated/compatibility functions.

Answer (score 2):

Notice in the C snippet it's the *pointer* to an int variable that is being passed to glGenVertexArrays - you're passing the memory address that should be populated with the generated ID value.

In Java you don't have the same concept of pointers to primitive types - in your snippet you're passing an integer *value*, not a pointer.
The API class you are trying to use does not have a `glGenVertexArrays(int, int)` method, hence your IDE is complaining.

Instead use either `glGenVertexArrays(int[])` or `glGenVertexArrays(IntBuffer)`, e.g.:

```
int[] vertexArrayIDs = new int[1]; // create an array where the generated ids will be stored
glGenVertexArrays(vertexArrayIDs); // no need to say how many IDs we want - it's implicit in the array length
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayIDs[0]) // access the array to get the generated ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for improving my code, but the method still does not exist - glGenVertexArrays "cannot be resolved".